# Not able to Parse JSON from Jenkins properly

Tags: javascript, json, api, jenkins

I'm trying to parse JSON from Jenkins's API using request

```
request({method: 'GET', url}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body.toString());
    var output_json = JSON.parse(body.toString());
    console.log(output_json);
}
```

After I parse the JSON usingJSON.parse(), few values in the tags are lost.

Console output of text output before parsing JSON

```
{
  "_class" : "My.FreeProject",
  "actions" : [
    {

    },
    {
      "_class" : "FreeProject.Property",
      "parameterDefinitions" : [
        {
          "_class" : "org.choice.Parameter",
          "defaultParameterValue" : {
            "_class" : "Property",
            "value" : "master19.7.0"
          },
          "description" : "",
          "name" : "BUILD_TAG",
          "type" : "ChoiceParameter"
        },
        {
          "_class" : "Parameter",
          "defaultParameterValue" : {
            "_class" : "Value",
            "value" : ""
          },
          "description" : "Random Text",
          "name" : "MY_TEST",
          "type" : "StringParameterDefinition"
        },
        {
          "_class" : "org.myclass",
          "defaultParameterValue" : {
            "_class" : "org.newclass"
          },
          "description" : "",
          "name" : "TESTING",
          "type" : "NodeParameterDefinition"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
```

Console output of text output after parsing JSON

```
{ _class: 'My.FreeProject',
  actions:
   [ {},
     { _class: 'FreeProject.Property',
       parameterDefinitions: [Object] },
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {},
     { _class: 'com.myclass' } ],
```

So after parsing JSON, I'm losing some of the text values. Is there a way I could retrieve all the information of the JSON from Jenkins? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anything is missing. The value of `parameterDefinitions` is just *collapsed*. Either there is a toggle you can click on to expand it, or use `console.dir` instead.

Example from the Chrome console. Note how it shows `[Array[1]]` instead of `[[[[]]]]` after parsing the string into an object. However, the values is still four nested arrays.

[image]

Comment: I overlooked the collapse part. Thanks